# How to retrieve kendoForm data?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I'm having trouble retrieving data from kendoUIForm. I have initialized three simple text fields and a dropdown, all inside a kendo form. When I click on submit button, I need to retrieve all data input and selected from user to use it somewhere else. Here is what I tried and currently it's not working.

```
  <div class="demo-section k-content">
    <div id="validation-success"></div>
    <form id="exampleform"></form>
  </div>
  
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      var validationSuccess = $("#validation-success");
      
      $("#exampleform").kendoForm({
        orientation: "vertical",
        items: [{
          type: "group",
          label: "Registration Form",
          items: [
            { field: "Username", label: "Username:", validation: { required: true } },
            { field: "Email", label: "Email:", validation: { required: true, email: true } },
            { field: "Password", label: "Password:", validation: { required: true }, 
             hint: "Hint: enter alphanumeric characters only.",
             editor: function(container, options) {
               container.append($("<input type='password' class='k-textbox k-valid' id='Password' name='Password' title='Password' required='required' autocomplete='off' aria-labelledby='Password-form-label' data-bind='value:Password' aria-describedby='Password-form-hint'>"));
             }
            },
            { field: "Country", editor: "ComboBox", label: "Country", validation: { required: true },
             editorOptions: {
               valuePrimitive: true,
               dataTextField: "text",
               dataValueField: "value",
               dataSource: [{ text: "country1", value: "1" },
                            { text: "country2", value: "2" },
                            { text: "country3", value: "3" },
                            { text: "country4", value: "4" }]
             }
            }
          ]
        }],
        
        validateField: function(e) {
          validationSuccess.html("");
        },
        submit: function(e) {
          var exFormData = $("exampleform").data("kendoForm").value();
          alert(exFormData);
          
          e.preventDefault();
          validationSuccess.html("<div class='k-messagebox k-messagebox-success'>Form data is valid!</div>");
        },
        clear: function(ev) {
          validationSuccess.html("");
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to accomplish getting the inputs data.

You can get access to the form, then search for the inputs you care about using find and a jquery selector. From here you can decide if you want to grab each input by id, or write a function to get all the input values from within the form, depending on your requirements.

In your submit function:

```
submit: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var exForm = $("#exampleform");
    console.log(exForm);
    console.log(exForm.find("#Email").val());

    validationSuccess.html("<div class='k-messagebox k-messagebox-success'>Form data is valid!</div>");
},
```

[Here is the above running in a dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/UmuqIKAd).